# find.package is deprecated in R

Tags: r

I have the following problem.
I get the following error message when loading the 'zoo' and 'xts' packages in R:

Warning messages:
        1: '.find.package' is deprecated.
        Use 'find.package' instead.
        See help("Deprecated")

It all works smoothly without error if I go to 'Package Installer' and run the update function. This is actually not a big problem but I have to do it every time I load the packages.

From the the help menu I understand that it has something to do with older packages not being compatible with the current version of R (at least this is how interpret it) but I have no idea how to fix the problem so that it does not occur again.

Can anyone help?

Thanks
H.

R version: 3.0.2
OS: Mac OS X 10.9

Comment: How are you loading the packages?

Comment: You could be using an old version of RStudio, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Read the NEWS ( ... and it's not an error, only a warning.)

```
"Public functions find.package() and path.package() replace the internal dot-name versions."
```

Comment: I had the similar "issue" installing R 3.0.2, i just installed the latest RStudio version and the warning is gone.